# git - checkout 2 projects simultaneously

Tags: git

I've got projects A and B (both separate git projects) that look like this:

```
A/some files
A/B/some more files
```

I added B to A but then when I tried to commit A there is no sign of B in the upstream repo which I assume is because B is its own git project.

I assume this is something to do with submodules but, in a nutshell, can I simply checkout both projects at the same time using a single git checkout command? Or do I need to do 2 separate command line invocations? e.g.

```
git checkout A; git checkout B;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are completely separate git repo's so they don't know about each other.  So commands will only take affect with the active repo.  See the active git repo with the command 'git rev-parse --git-dir'

Invoking the command line you have shown would not work because, by default, git determines the active repository and working tree by the current directory. Instead use

```
cd path_to_A/A
git rev-parse --git-dir 
git checkout MyBranchInA
cd B
git rev-parse --git-dir
git checkout MyBranchInB
```

Git submodules are not involved because they have not been setup.  You could set up one up with 'git submodule add', see also 'git sub-tree' which does the samething only (they say) better. for help on these commands see 'git help submodule' and 'git help subtree'

Answer (score 0):

They are two separate git projects. They have there own repos, their own heads. So no. You can not use one command by default.

Each .git folder contains all of the repo information.

[image]

This is where git knows where to push and what head/repo it is pointing at. git is only aware of the git repo in the current directory with the .git directory.

More clarification: 
If you make a change in project B and then do a commit while in A

```
git add .
git commit -m "I'm in project A directory"
```

This would only effect repo A. So doing a

```
git clone {url to B}
```

would not reflect these changes

Answer (score 0):

If they are indeed two separate but related projects, You could use [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to make parent project aware of the dependency. You could then setup repository hooks as you like to get the behavior you desired.